# How can G-d without form produce sound (voice)?

Tags: theology

How can a G-d without form produce sound (voice)? For instance, G-d spoke at Mount Sinai to millions of Jews.

Comment: Why are you asking about voice and not a G-d without form smiting the Egyptians? Or, for that matter, creating the world.

Comment: Maybe G-d didn't actually speak. Maybe he communicated telepathically at Har Sinai. דברה תורה כלשון בני אדם. But I second @rosends comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained by Rambam, God does not actually have a "voice". God is simply described that way because that is how the human mind can understand the nature of communication.

**Guide for the Perplexed 1:46**

> The perception by the senses, especially by hearing and seeing, is best known to us; we have no idea or notion of any other mode of communication between the soul of one person and that of another than by means of speaking, i.e., by the sound produced by lips, tongue, and the other organs of speech. When, therefore, we are to be informed that God has a knowledge of things, and that communication is made by Him to the Prophets who convey it to us, they represent Him to us as seeing and hearing, i.e., as perceiving and knowing those things which can be seen and heard. They represent Him to us as speaking, i.e., that communications from Him reach the Prophets; that is to be understood by the term "prophecy," as will be fully explained. God is described as working, because we do not know any other mode of producing a thing except by direct touch. He is said to have a soul in the sense that He is living, because all living beings are generally supposed to have a soul; although the term soul is, as has been shown, a homonym.
>
> Again, since we perform all these actions only by means of corporeal organs, we figuratively ascribe to God the organs of locomotion, as feet, and their soles; organs of hearing, seeing, and smelling, as ear, eye, and nose; organs and substance of speech, as mouth, tongue, and sound; organs for the performance of work, as hand, its fingers, its palm, and the arm. In short, these organs of the body are figuratively ascribed to God, who is above all imperfection, to express that He performs certain acts; and these acts are figuratively ascribed to Him to express that He possesses certain perfections different from those acts themselves. E.g., we say that He has eyes, ears, hands, a mouth, a tongue, to express that He sees, hears, acts, and speaks: but seeing and hearing are attributed to Him to indicate simply that He perceives. You thus find in Hebrew instances in which the perception of the one sense is named instead of the other; thus, "See the word of the Lord" (Jer. ii, 31), in the same meaning as "Hear the word of the Lord," for the sense of the phrase is, "Perceive what He says"; similarly the phrase, "See the smell of my son" (Gen. xxvii. 27) has the same meaning as "Smell the smell of my son," for it relates to the perception of the smell. In the same way are used the words, "And all the people saw the thunders and the lightnings" (Exod. xx. 15), although the passage also contains the description of a prophetical vision, as is well known and understood among our people. Action and speech are likewise figuratively applied to God, to express that a certain influence has emanated from Him, as will be explained (chap. lxv and chap. lxvi.)([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp056.htm))

**Guide for the Perplexed 1:65**

> AFTER YOU have advanced thus far, and truly comprehended that God exists
> without having the attribute of existence, and that He is One, without having the attribute of unity, I do not think that I need explain to you the inadmissibility of the attribute of speech in reference to God, especially since our people generally believe that the Law, i.e., the word ascribed to Him, was created. Speech is attributed to Him, in so far as the word which Moses heard, was produced and brought to existence by God in the same manner as He produced all His other works and creations. As we shall have to speak more fully on prophecy, we shall here merely show that speech is attributed to God in the same way as all other actions, which are similar to our own. When we are told that God addressed the Prophets and spoke to them, our minds are merely to receive a notion that there is a Divine knowledge to which the Prophets attain; we are to be impressed with the idea that the things which the Prophets communicate to us come from the Lord, and are not altogether the products of their own conceptions and ideas. ([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp075.htm))

**Ibid**

> The two terms, when applied to God, can only have one of the two last-mentioned significations, viz., he wills and he desires, or he thinks, and there is no difference whether the divine thought became known to man by means of an actual voice, or by one of those kinds of inspiration which I shall explain further on (II. chap. xxxviii.). We must not suppose that in speaking God employed voice or sound. or that He has a soul in which the thoughts reside, and that these thoughts are things superadded to His essence; but we ascribe and attribute to Him thoughts in the same manner as we ascribe to Him any other attributes. ([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp075.htm))

Comment: Do you really think it is readable and understandable? I doubt. Can you bold the right lines to prove your point.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever Moses went into the Tent of Meeting to speak with Him, he would hear the Voice speaking to him from above the kapporet that was on top of the Ark of the Testimony, between the two cherubim; thus He spoke to him (Numbers 7:89).

Not so with My servant Moses; he is trusted throughout My household. With him I speak mouth to mouth, plainly and not in riddles, and he gazes upon the likeness of the LORD(Numbers 12:7–8).

DIVREY   YA'AKOV Chapter 3 verse 3:  In  shaar  3:  chapter  11,  he  elaborates  further  that  the  whole world  was  formed  by  the  command  of  Hashem,  as  recorded  in parshat  Bereishit.    For  each  thing  Hashem  said  that  it  would  be, and  so  it  was.  The  word  of  Hashem  is  a  real  spiritual  entity  with power  to  generate  the  entire  existence  of  the  world.  He  explains further  that  the  spiritual  reality  of  Hashem’s  word  is  eternal  and does  not  end  with  the  days  of  creation.  These  continuously existing  commands  sustain  and  support  everything  in  the  world, like  the  living  soul  of  all  existence.

4. He  also  writes  on  the  verse  in  Yeshayahu  (40:5),  “And  all  flesh together  will  see  that  the  mouth  of  Hashem  has  spoken”.  “The verse  refers  to  the  future  time  when  Hashem’s  supervision  will be  so  clear,  until  we  merit  literally  seeing  with  our  physical  eyes, how  the  word  of  Hashem  is  spread  out  over  every  thing sustaining  it”  -  see  the  text  inside  for  his  full  essay.
5. He  adds  that  there  was  already  a  sample  glimpse  of  this concept  at  Mt.  Sinai  at  the  giving  of  the  Torah.  This  is  referred to  in  the  verse  in  Parshat  Yitro  (20:18),  “And  all  the  people  **saw** the  sounds”  [The  simple  meaning  here  is  the  sounds  which occurred  uniquely  at  the  Mt.  Sinai  event.  But  there  are  many ways  and  perceptions  of  the  Torah,  as  is  clear  from  Chazal,  and there  are  many  understandings  to  every  verse  given  at  Sinai. There  are  the  simple  meanings,  and  the  meanings  which  are hinted  to  within  the  words,  that  which  can  be  expounded  from it,  and  the  hidden  secrets  of  it].  Here  the  sounds  refer  to  the sounds  of  the  word  of  Hashem  at  the  time  of  the  creation  of  the world,  meaning  that  they  **merited  seeing**  how  this  voice  is  the soul  of  the  creation,  sustaining  it  in  its  entirety.  See  how  this  is explained  later  in  the  chapter  of  the  giving  of  the  Torah  at  Mt. Sinai.

Comment: A belated welcome to Mi Yodeya. How exactly does this answer the question? The OP asked how it’s possible for an intangible G-d to have a voice; these are *supports* for the question, not *answers.*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35783)

Comment: @DannySchoemann I didn't unlock the comment section, since I am a newcomer to stack exchange community.

Comment: @Ezra By now you have unlocked it.

Comment: @Alex Yes, I have B"H.

Comment: @Ezra - that's a canned phrase when a reviewer clicks "Does not answer the question". please don't take it personally.

Answer (score 1):

The philosopher Philo (20 BCE-50 CE) wrote that G-d did not "speak" because G-d does not have vocal cords. G-d is not anthropomorphic. Thereby, G-d created a miraculous sound that pronounced the commands.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the question is legitimate and there are a couple of possibilities:

1. G-d's control over the matter is absolute, He could create sound waves out of nothing, without a physical source.
2. G-d's control over people minds is also absolute. He could create a sense of sound in the heads of millions without creating sound waves in the first place.
3. G-d's control over people's memory could allow planting artificial memories in the heads of millions.

Either way, what's important is that according to the Bible, millions of Jews had this memory of G-d speaking to them.

Comment: Is there a source that G-d took control of people's minds or memory? And if so, where is the free will in choosing to accept the Torah or not?

Comment: I just read an article stating that we understood rather than heard a voice. In this sense, a person could choose to accept or deny based on their understanding with everyone received the same.

Comment: I might add that in the account in Sh'mot, it says the people SAW voices.

Comment: @AlBerko I don’t disagree with Turk’s first comment here. Your third point is *very* close to heresy, if one were to continue that thought process down that very slippery slope.

Comment: @DonielF Do you dare to challenge that assumption that G-d does not control our minds? Isn't it any closer to heresy? Just kidding. the OP does not understand the whole issue of Free Choice, but it is a different question.

Comment: @DonielF Just for you, think about אני היום ילדתיך - שיהיו כל הימים חדשים בעיניך.  Can you prove you existed yesterday and were not created this morning when you woke up with all of your memories? I doubt.

Comment: @AlBerko What you’re proposing is that Ma’amad Har Sinai never happened, or at least, based on the mechanics you’ve set up, it would be plausible for one to say such a thing. Ma’amad Har Sinai absolutely happened, and it wasn’t an implanted fake memory.

Comment: @AlBerko You can’t disprove the Church of the Flying Spaghetti Monster - that’s their whole shtick, that it can’t be disproven.

Comment: @DonielF Don't get me wrong, I understand completely the consequences of my statements, I'm just saying it is a possibility we can't disprove. What difference does it make if G-d speaks to 6M people or plants memories in 6M people?

Comment: @AlBerko How is our acceptance of the Torah binding if we never actually accepted it?

Comment: @DonielF Good Q. By me, it's the experience and the belief that obligates. I know the drill, the "common knowledge" etc, I'm just talking quantum physics to a Newtonian guy. I have some proofs of what I'm saying, e.g. the Torah obligated before it was given, but ut us not for this OP.

Comment: @AlBerko You mean, the reason why we, in 2018, are obligated to observe the Torah, is just belief in Hashem? Not what the Gemara says, that all of us, even those who weren’t alive yet, were at Har Sinai? The Torah wasn’t binding before it was given - the Avos observed it, yes, but they weren’t *obligated* to do so.

Comment: @DonielF It's hard to discuss it with you if you only have two terms - either *obligated* or not. I have a BA in Psychology and I know all a person has is his imagination, there's nothing that *obligates* or not. You have pictures in your head and you have little idea where from. If they are consistent - you're lucky but there's nothing that "obligates you" - it is your imagination.

Comment: @AlBerko If a principal tells a student that he must do XYZ or else he will be thrown out of the school, I’d call that being obligated. Whether the student listens or not is a different issue. I will agree that certain mitzvos are חובות - obligations - and certain mitzvos are רשויות - permissions - but there’s still a concept of schar v’onesh that’s enforced. And you still haven’t addressed the Gemara. If you want to look it up inside, it’s Shevuos 39a.

Comment: @DonielF I truly understand you. That feeling of the "objective reality". Don't get me wrong, I'm not questioning your stand. I told you, you're a Newtonian guy, and the Newtonian laws still work. However a new wind of relativity is blowing everywhere and also in Judaism. The old concepts that held for 2000 years start shaking, needing new explanations and definitions... This has nothing to do with this question, the OP should just ignore my #2 or 3.

Comment: @AlBerko You’re making up stuff with no basis for them. If you’re going to claim that there’s a new “quantum mechanics” in Hashkafa, you need to demonstrate that. Otherwise your answers relying on that should be edited out, rather than you telling everyone to ignore them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85883/discussion-between-al-berko-and-donielf).

Comment: @DonielF Indeed, R. Abraham of Viterbo in Sefer Emunas Chachamim ([end of Ma'amar Shlishi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43991&st=&pgnum=69)) explains that it doesn't mean that we were actually present at Sinai, but that we inherit the obligations that our ancestors accepted.